# How to make a function that lays mines to random squares on nested list?

Tags: python, list, random, nested

The field is created like this:

```
field = []
for row in range(10):
   field.append([])
   for col in range(15):
      field[-1].append(" ")
```

Tuples represent free squares where mines can be layed

```
free = []
for x in range(15):
   for y in range(10):
      free.append((x, y))
```

I have to lay the mines trough this function:

```
def lay_mines(field, free, number_of_mines):

    for _ in number_of_mines:
        mines = random.sample(free, number_of_mines)
        field(mines) = ["x"]
```

I was thinking using random.sample() or random.choice(). I just can't get it to work. How can I place the string "x" to a certain random coordinate?

Comment: What means "can't get it to work"? Edit the question to explain what happens. If there is an error message show its full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call because of  `field(mines) = ["x"]`

Comment: `mines = random.sample(free, number_of_mines)` has to be placed before the loop begins but then what?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def lay_mines(x, y, number_of_mines=0):
    f = [list(' ' * x) for _ in range(y)]
    for m in random.sample(range(x * y), k=number_of_mines): # random sampling without replacement
        f[m % y][m // y] = 'X'
    return f

field = lay_mines(15, 10, 20)
print(*field, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```